# How can I make hash page title and first content hide

Tags: jquery, hash, master-pages, hide, title

I can't when I enter url value so title don't change and first content don't hide how can use with enter with url change title and hide first pagecontent ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
    var pagecontent = $(".page_content");
    var pages = $("ul.pages li,#logo");
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    var title = document.title;

    pagecontent.not(hash).hide();
    pages.first().addClass("active").show();
    pagecontent.first().show();
    pages.find('[href=' + hash + ']').addClass('active');
    pages.find('[href=' + hash + ']').parent().closest('li').addClass('active');

    pages.click(function() {
        $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent().closest('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active'); 
        pagecontent.hide();
        var activepage = $(this).find("a").attr("href");

        $(activepage).fadeIn();
        title = $('h2', activepage).first().text();   
        $('title').text(title);
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

When I tried to enter the url does not change the title and pagecontent.first remain there

Comment: I really think you need to take a few moments and try to work out how to rephrase your question; currently I have no idea what it is that you're asking for help with. What problem are you having?

Comment: When I tried to enter the url does not change the title and pagecontent.first remain there

Comment: When I tried to enter the url I want see activepage title and first pagecontent hide

Comment: Can you provide [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with markup and the script, and the URL?

Comment: Thank you, but I found like this http://jsfiddle.net/aRyd4/

Comment: Please, put your markup there (HTML).

Comment: sorry look this http://jsfiddle.net/aRyd4/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. Here it is:

```
$(function() {
    var pagecontent = $(".page_content");
    var pages = $("ul.pages li,#logo");
    var hash = window.location.hash || "#home";
    var title = document.title;

    // new block
    var titlex = $('h2', hash).first().text();
    document.title = titlex;
    $(hash).show();

    $('ul.pages a[href="' + hash + '"]')
        .addClass("active")
        .closest("li")
            .addClass("active");
    // end

    pagecontent.not(hash).hide();
    pages.click(function() {
        $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent().closest('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active'); 
        pagecontent.hide();
        var activepage = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
        window.location.hash = activepage;  //new: fix location hash
        $(activepage).fadeIn();
        title = $('h2', activepage).first().text();   
         $('title').text(title);
        return false;
    });
});
```

We could discuss the style but this works.

EDIT: Note that `click` handler sets appropriate location hash. Seems like right decision but it causes flicker in browser title bar. If it bothers you, try replacing

```
window.location.hash = activepage;
$('title').text(title);
```

with

```
if( history.pushState ) {
    history.replaceState({}, title, activepage);
} else {
    window.location.hash = activepage;
    document.title = title;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean "Home"? Strange. I see it on load. AHA! You mean, if there's no hash part in address. Fixed, the default is "#home".

Comment: and latest i want ask something. Why does the title flash shake ?

Comment: @Blitzer Clark what do you mean?

Comment: when i click a link title change 2 time

Comment: how can i change this code like pushstate I'm trying to learn, but I could not find 3 days i want example.com/home i dont want # this. I've found some code but bad when i make reflesh 404 error or when i enter url value 404 error.You know you are a good example of pushstate or Would you assist me ?

Comment: @Blitzer Clark: Why don't you start another question? You have working code and want to get rid of hash part of URL. I believe you want some degree of compatibility with major browsers, too.